# What to call the intermediate layer of the program?

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

We have a program consisting of three parts. There's the backend which is the NT service handling the requests. Also there's a COM object that implements a predefined interface, is consumed by client software and passes the requests to the service.

Since we need to have both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the COM object we split it into two parts:

1. the front end that implements the
   predefined interface
2. the middle layer that implements a
   newly introduced intermediate
   interface and is hosted in COM+ to
   avoid reimplementing everything as
   both 32 and 64 bit.

So the front end forwards requests to the intermediate layer, the intermediate layer forwards them to the back end.

The problem is that the front end is the first thing the customers "see" and we don't like to call it "Our Product Front end", but rather just call it "Our Product". We also need to invent a good name for the intermediate layer. What's typically used for the latter?

So far the most suitable match I found in the dictionary is *spacer level* - concise and somehow reflects what the layer is for. Will that do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term applied to the middle tier can be influenced by its role. Typically, it is a controller in an MVC paradigm, a business logic layer, a communication/transport layer or a combination of these.

Terms I've used:

Middle Tier (admittedly a generic cop-out -- could apply to your situation)

Business Logic Layer or Business Objects - not the best fit for your app...

Transport Layer -- seems more apt to your situation, though I'm not convinced "everybody will immediately know what you're talking about" when you introduce this term.

Controller (probably too abstract -- Model-View-Controller)

Comment: I guess the middle tier will do - concise, neutral, not revealing any details and not conflicting with domain knowledge users possibly have.

Answer (score 1):

Could always try going with "Data-Access Layer"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Translation layer?

Answer (score 0):

We've recently coined the term "Intermediary Layer"